# Azure DevOps Pull Request trigger not appearing in release pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I'm trying to create a release pipeline with PR trigger. I saw in every documentation, that there should be a "Pull Request trigger" toggle in the artifact like here:
[image: Pull request trigger in documentation]
However when I click the Continuous deployment trigger icon, there is no Pull request trigger:
[image: No PR trigger]
I don't know what I'm doing wrong, I followed every step from Microsoft's documentation.
On stage triggers it shows the PR trigger option with a warning:
[image: PR trigger with warning]

I created multiple new pipelines, the toggle just doesn't show up. The artifact is built from code on Github

Comment: Have you set up the configs on GitHub side.
You need to setup both Azure and Github in order for the trigger to work.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/github-actions?view=azure-devops

Comment: What do you mean, where can I configure this? The build pipeline works fine, when there is a PR, the build pipeline builds the artifact, but then the relase pipeline not triggered.

Comment: I'm also getting this issue on a deployment pipeline as well where the artifact doesn't have the pipeline trigger option to select. Interestingly, this artifact did previously have it so is there anything in the build, deployment or repo logic behind the scenes driving whether the PR trigger shows?

I can add artifacts from other projects and some do have the trigger, some do not - including when I use the affected source in a new, clean pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

This situation may be if you are using Team Foundation Version Control for your builds:

[image]

TFVC does not support pull requests. Please, verify you are trying to use GIT in your build pipeline:
[image]

Comment: The build pipeline is correct, it builds from code from Github fine, it is triggered by commits and pool requests also, the release pipeline seems to be not working.

Answer (score 0):

To ensure the uniqueness of every artifact download, each artifact source linked to a release pipeline is automatically provided with a specific download location known as the source alias. Please see the official doc for more details: [Artifact source alias](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/artifacts?view=azure-devops#artifact-source-alias)

I notice:
1.The original build name own '*'.
2.Your source alias without the download location '*'.

if I change the source alias by cutting the '_', chances are not seeing the pull request trigger part. It's not related to repo location, repo type when you choose build type artifact.
[image]

The workaround is:
If your artifact source alias name doesn't have '*'or'-', then you could cut the system added '*'.
If you do want cut the system added '*', please don't add '*' in artifact source alias name.

For your reference, if you want to change artifact source alias name, you can change the name of the build pipeline.

I hope this could do some help.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, I should not remove the "_" character, when I add the artifact to the release pipeline?

Comment: Yes, please go ahead to have a try. I will appreciate if you could tell whether it helps.

Comment: I added a new artifact without changing the name, but nothing changed, still the PR trigger not showing up.

Comment: Hi @Fulcrum, do you still use build Source type? What about new a simple repo in devops with only readme file then run the build with the simple tasks(NuGet restore-》NuGet pack-》Visual Studio build-》Copy files-》Publish build artifacts) to generate an artifact(with the simple name such as 'testartifact') and use it in release with build Source type to see whether you could see the pull request trigger on your side? Thanks.